# How to select all same elements and get each id in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wan't to select all the section tags inside the body and get each id attribute.
I'm using the logic below:

```
<body>
  <section id="header"></section>
  <section id="content" ></section>
</body>
```

the ideal "fantasy" code I'd like to achieve:

```
var select_all_section = $('body * section');
var sec_id = select_all_section.attr('id');

console.log(sec_id);
//OUTPUT: header
//OUTPUT: content
```

my actual code

```
var select_all_section = $('body > section');
var sec_id = select_all_section.attr('id');

console.log(sec_id);
//OUTPUT: header
```

Comment: "get the ID" ... get it *where*? As an array? Separate?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so, I don't know why you need it, but here's a way to output each of them individually.

```js
var $ids = $('section');

$ids.each(function(i,e){
  console.log($(e).attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="header" >
</section>
<section id="content" >
</section>
```

Edit : Actually, I think http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/ would be even better than this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [.map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)

```js
$(function() {
  var select_all_section = $('section');
  var sec_id = select_all_section.map(function() {
    return this.id;
  });
  console.log(sec_id)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="header">
</section>
<section id="content">
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("section")` will get you already a collection of all your elements.

So you can go directly with

```
$("section").css({color:"red", fontSize:"24px"});
```

or if you really need the ID to use it to do more interesting stuff...

### Using `.prop()`

[`.prop( propertyName, function )`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-function) will access a desired property

```js
$("section").prop("id", function(idx, val){
  console.log(val);
});
```

```html
<section id="header"></section>
<section id="content"></section>
<section id="footer"></section>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### Using `.map()`

```js
var sectionIDs = $("section").map(function() {
  return this.id;
}).get();

console.log( sectionIDs.join("\n") );  // Join with newline
console.log( sectionIDs );             // Show as array
```

```html
<section id="header"></section>
<section id="content"></section>
<section id="footer"></section>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### Using `.each()`

this method is useful if you need to do more `this` related stuff bound to every of those elements, but OK, here's a simple example

```js
$("section").each(function() {
  console.log( this.id );  
  // Or using jQuery 
  // console.log( $(this).prop("id") );
});
```

```html
<section id="header"></section>
<section id="content"></section>
<section id="footer"></section>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### Using pure JavaScript

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("section")).forEach( e => console.log(e.id) );
```

```html
  <section id="header"></section>
  <section id="content"></section>
  <section id="footer"></section>
```

Comment: It is a very clever and unusual way of using the prop method. You should warn about not to return anything else than undefined too

Comment: the .prop() method works, how can I do this: var x = '#'+val; x.css(" ", " ");

Comment: @MarvenWilsonSDonque like this: `$('#'+val).css({color: "#f00"});`

Comment: @MarvenWilsonSDonque but that's the same as doing `$(this).css({color:"red"});` or even without all of the above: `$("section").css({color:"red"})`